# Conversion of Integer

Tags: javascript, integer, numbers, biginteger

How would I convert Int 623527832412487691 to Int 623527832412487691n without the number changing value

I don't want Int 623527832412487691 to turn to Int 623527832412487700 as apparently JavaScript does some conversion to BigInt

I have

```
let string = 623527832412487691

console.log(string)
```

and it prints 623527832412487700

Comment: you want `let myNumber = 623427832412487691n;` or `let myNumber = BigInt("623427832412487691";)`

Comment: A BigInt constant ends with an "n", like `623527832412487691n`.

Comment: Aside: please don't name any variable `string` . Use that reserved keyword for your string type declarations.

Comment: yes, my original integer is 623427832412487691, how do i change it to 623427832412487691n

Comment: In your code as given, you just type `n` at the end of the number. Is there something else that prevents you from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a limitation on the precision of integer values due to the way it represents numbers using the double-precision floating-point format. The number you provided exceeds the maximum safe integer in JavaScript (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`), that is, 9007199254740991. Once you go beyond this limit, you start losing precision.

[image: Illustrating Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER]

To handle large integers accurately in JavaScript without losing precision, you can use the BigInt data type, introduced in ECMAScript 2020. However, when initializing a BigInt directly from a literal, JavaScript will still use floating-point arithmetic if the number is too large.

To handle your specific case, you can convert your number to a BigInt using the BigInt constructor.

```js
let number = 623527832412487691n;
console.log(number);
```

Here, 623527832412487691n explicitly represents a BigInt without any loss of precision. This way, you won't face the issue of JavaScript converting the number to a floating-point representation.

If you have the number as a string, you can explicitly convert it to a BigInt by doing the following:

```js
let string = "623527832412487691";
let bigintNumber = BigInt(string);
console.log(bigintNumber);
```

***Updates based on further comments***

*Update 1*:

While retrieving a value from a MySQL database column that stores numbers as strings, you can ensure that it remains a string by explicitly converting it to a string after retrieving it. You can use either `String()` or `.toString()` functions for this.

```js
let data = db.prepare('SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE userid = ?').get(interaction.user.id);

let numberAsString = String(data.yourNumberColumn); // Replace 'yourNumberColumn' with the actual column name

console.log(numberAsString);

// Explicit type conversion to BigInt as shown above in original answer
let numberAsBigInt = BigInt(data.yourNumberColumn); 

console.log(numberAsBigInt);
```

With explicit type conversions, you avoid automatic conversion to a number in JavaScript.

[image: Explicit Type Conversion]

Comment: I understand it with strings, however, my starting point is the exact Int 623527832412487691 nothing else, not with the n at the end and if I do

```
let myNumber = 623527832412487691

console.log(myNumber.toString())
```

it converts to 623527832412487700

Comment: @Alfie how are you receiving this data? For numbers that big you should be receiving it as a string.

Comment: I am getting the number through an array, in which the number is stored as an Integer, I retrieve the number I want and try to store it in my database in a column which stores strings, I then pull the data out for future use and it automatically converts to the Integer I do not want. If I use a MySQL database viewer, in the database it's fine and is a string, just when I retrieve the data it turns into a number I do not want.

Comment: How are you retrieving it from the database, and how are you transmitting it to JavaScript? You want to prevent converting it to a number in the first place (at least you don't want to give it to JavaScript as a number). This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), as JavaScript cannot do the thing you want it to do.

Comment: This is me retreiving the data https://imgur.com/Y8zCIIc with the interaction.user.id which is 623527832412487691 bút when I print it it goes to 623527832412487700

Comment: I have updated the answer to incorporate the comments. You basically need to look into explicit type conversions.